# Page displayed insecure content when using Google Play services to display ads

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads, flurry

I am trying to implement flurry ads in one of my android applications. In order to do this I have to reference the Google play services library. I have done successfully. When I run the application from Eclipse, everything works fine. When I sign the application and install the signed apk on the same device, I get the following errors in LogCat and no ads on the related page:

> 06-02 16:40:20.475: W/Ads(12718): JS: The page at about:blank
>   displayed insecure content from
>   gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_scenario=online_request&type=gwhirl&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fmediate%3Fsession_id%3D2339733085326413666%26seq_num%3D3%26slotname%3D0e3c34db9b3b4d05%26rm%3D1%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v4452000.4030500.1%26eid%3D46621036%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D28001%26u_sd%3D2%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26muv%3D15%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DY7TSXr_AH6DpzO4c1mg1q98qMTwt3yqB4hkt5GJSAL8YV2zijxAK5Sp-lxSHn3Gf-K7j5y3xNa5Ffx3jyllKCghvWkxxmqX4REQ5xY0PMntbudWqrCHppgc-oVRWGsa29_4IVy6HgwfnjouomM73n2-E46fJUqJypOlcBNVuOd_2Crjz8sGcU0dK_D-HOUfxpjUjXzYdNd0oC85uLm1jwjgfed3T3IiZMWbnvJGVrb-zuvlUozE8Kg2fahg_dC4ELm2lpekXg1WpMvssXfEmaQAfpthkYgDsYF-0CayooFg51TdbFALo9mXLo5cWw8BnFOXjCnFFmtj22lBD_QbUiw%26mv%3D80260017.com.android.vending%26format%3D360x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26am%3D0%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D640%26msid%3Dcom.test.adftest%26app_name%3D67.android.com.test.adftest%26an%3D67.android.com.test.adftest%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D2%26pimp%3D0%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D94908600%26currts%3D96288395%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D180%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26gsb%3Dwi%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26jsv%3D91%26urll%3D1057&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fmediate&use_webview_loadurl=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1401716420476.

Any clues as to what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a problem with my proguard settings. I used a fresh proguard file (with default settings) and everything works fine now.

Ads are displayed now but in the logcat, the above warning pops up every time it tries to load an ad. Is there a problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error:

The view where you're trying to show ads is deleted from the parent view.
be sure that

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutAdmobGame"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="52dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

This within its parent view and has not been removed

Answer (score 0):

Update your xml layout according to new policy of AdMob. AdView must be placed correctly, ads should not be placed over the other application content.

Please read admob updated publisher policy and guidelines [here](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2936217).